# Robotium side scroll not working for me

Tags: android, testing, junit, scroll, robotium

I want to scroll left/right on an android application using a Robotium/Junit test.

There is a function in Robotium called:

```
solo.scrollToSide(int);
```

But, what do I put for the int?  what is the value for RIGHT and what is the value for LEFT?  I tried 0,1,2,3, and 4... no luck :(

Thanks

***EDIT:***

**I found the answer.  RIGHT is 22 and LEFT is 21.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use Solo.RIGHT and Solo.LEFT.

Comment: Cool, thanks... that's better than 22 & 21 :)

This works:
         `solo.scrollToSide(Solo.RIGHT); //right`

Answer (score 0):

This might also work -
To scroll to Left
solo.scrollToSide(Solo.LEFT);

To scroll to Right
solo.scrollToSide(Solo.RIGHT);

Comment: I believe this answer has already been given. I see no need to essentially repeat [Renas' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9485913/499214).